# How to get the created / last DDL time for an Oracle synonym?

Tags: oracle, ddl, synonym

SQL Developer shows the creation and last DDL time for a public synonym in a table:

```
CREATED         15-AUG-09
LAST_DDL_TIME   15-AUG-09
OWNER           PUBLIC
SYNONYM_NAME    ISEMPTY
TABLE_OWNER     MDSYS
TABLE_NAME      OGC_ISEMPTY
DB_LINK     (null)
```

How can I get the same information via a SQL query?

```
select *  from all_synonyms where synonym_name = 'ISEMPTY'
```

does not get the created/last ddl dates.

More generally, is there a good way to see the queries that sql developer uses to display the data it displays (when you do not have access to a profiler)?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [ALL_OBJECTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1155.htm#REFRN20146) system view:

```
select *
  from all_objects
 where owner = 'OWNER_NAME'
   and object_name = 'ISEMPTY'
   and object_type = 'SYNONYM'
```